Finding the first two variational equations for this IVP
I am currently in Chapter 2.5 of Teschl's ODE script on page 46, and I have been given the following problem that I am struggling with:
Find and solve the first two variational equations of the initial value problem:
$\dot{x} = 2t(x + 1) \\  
x(0) = x_0$
In the Script the first variational equation is given by
$\dot{y} = A(t,x)y, \ \ \ \ \ \ A(t,x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, \phi(t, t_0, x))$
where $\phi(t, t_0, x)$ solves the IVP $\dot{x} = f(x,t), x(0) = x_0$.
Since $\dot{x} = 2t(x+1)$ is separable, I was able to find a solution which is
$$x(t) = (1+x_0)e^{t^2} - 1$$
The first variational equation can be found by taking the derivative of $f(x,t)$ with respect to $x$ and we get
$$\dot{y} = 2ty$$
To find the second variational equation, I wanted to use theorem 2.10 of the script which states
$"$Suppose $f \in C^{k}(U, R^{n}), k \geq 1$. Around each point $(t_0, x_0) \in U$ we can find an open set $I \times B \subseteq U$ such that $\phi(t, s, x) \in C^{k}(I \times I \times B, R^{n})$.
Moreover, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi(t, s, x) \in C^{k}(I \times I \times B, R^{n})$ and if $D_k$ is a partial derivative of order $k$, then $D_k\phi$ satisfies the higher order variational equation obtained from
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}D_k\phi(t, s, x) = D_k\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi(t, s, x) = D_kf(t, \phi(t, s, x))$$
by applying the chain rule. In particular, this equation is linear in $D_k\phi$ and it also follows that the corresponding higher order derivatives commute.$"$
I now have two questions:

Is my approach for the first variational equation correct? I’m a little unsure whether I’ve done everything correctly.

I am having difficulty applying the theorem to the second variational equation because, to be honest, I don’t fully understand it. Could someone show me a solution method or how to apply the theorem?



Is there really nobody who could help me? :-(
